# How to stop android CTS with saving the current results?

Tags: android, android-cts

Is this a command that gives opportunity to stop the running CTS test, for further look through the results, and then continuing running the rest of CTS test?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you. you can simply remove your device physically and then wait for enough long time, the testing session will automatically close and save the results. After this you exit the cts-tf shell or reboot your pc and restart cts-tf shell and then restart your old session with the option of --retry.

Answer (score -1):

execute in kill command in cts shell

```
cts>kill
```